# Magento - New Products shows wrong product view

Tags: php, magento

In my Magento installation I have a category that uses a view.phtml that is different from all other views. In my category settings I use this for Custom Layout Update:

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>catalog/product/view_stoffen.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```

But when I click on a product from this category via my New Products widget at my homepage, I get the standard view.phtml.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set `Apply to Products` to `Yes`. Aside from that, make sure your namespace and path for your custom view are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override in your template the `catalog.xml` layout for the `catalog_product_view` and set the template there like this

```
........
<reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view_stoffen.phtml">
.....
```

you can do this by copying the `catalog.xml` from the base template to yours and editing it

hope it helps

Comment: Well, I only use this template for 1 category, all the others have the standard template?

Comment: your question is not clear to me. If your are trying to use a custom template for only 1 category, i think you will need something more than xml, maybe some php code to validate for the category and then change the template in the action for that specific category. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I have indeed one specific category that needs a different view. But if I navigate through my catalog to a product in this category, the view is correct. But if I click through my widget "New Products" on the homepage, he takes the default view.

Comment: Did you compare the product link url in the catalog with the link url in the widget? Are the same?

Comment: No they aren't. With the widget the category is missing but how can I fix? It just uses getProductUrl() method....

Comment: Would you edit your question and describe how did you created the widget and what is the difference between the 2 links url?